# Dotnet program crashing when stepping into async method in Rider on M1 Mac

Tags: .net-core, rider

Recently my IDE has been behaving oddly when debugging - whenever I try to step into an async method (C#), the debugging session immediately ends. Like this:

[image: GIF of the issue in action]

**My question:**
What else can I do to investigate / troubleshoot, and can anyone shed any insight into what might be happening?

More specifics, what I've tried, etc. below.

---

I first noticed this in an AspNetCore application but it is reproducible in a simple console app, as in the GIF. Here's the code I used to reproduce it.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Start");

// Can step into fine
Hello();

// Step into immediately crashes program
await HelloAsync(); 

Console.WriteLine("End");

void Hello() {
    Console.Write("Hello sync");
}

async Task HelloAsync() {
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.Write("Hello async");
}
```

---

Here's what I know so far:

- This only started happening recently, right around the time I installed dotnet 7 (though could be a coincidence, I can't remember if it was *exactly* after)
- I dumped the rider logs (posted below), and it looks like Rider just spontaneously loses connection to the dotnet debugger (as if the debugger process crashed)
- **Update** I found some more logs that show the debugger didn't crash, the target program did. Posted those logs below too.
- This doesn't happen on Visual Studio for Mac, but it does on the three most recent versions of Rider (and they definitely didn't before now; I've been using Rider for years)

I'm on an M1 Macbook Pro, so not sure if this is related to some ARM teething issues.

Here's what I've tried:

- Installing different versions of Rider
- Uninstalling all versions of the .NET SDK, and reinstalling each version individually (i.e. dotnet 6 by itself, with no 7, and vice-versa)
- Re-targeting my demo app from .NET 6 to .NET 7 (I found I was forced to do this to run it with the .NET 7 SDK anyway)
- Restarting my system

I'm about to post a bug report to Jetbrains as well, but I'd like to try to dig further into it myself in the meantime, because it feels like a problem between Rider and my system ( / my dotnet installation), and it may be specific to me.

---

**Relevant sections of the Rider logs**

```
07:04:14.312 |V| RiderDebuggerSessionFrontend  | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerToFrontend-Receiver:13 | Debugger command received from frontend: StepIntoActionModel ()
07:04:14.371 |I| CorRuntimeEventProcessor      | Debugger worker MTA main thread:6 | Target process exited
07:04:14.372 |V| RiderDebuggerSessionFrontend  | Debugger worker MTA main thread:6 | Event from debugger: type TargetExited
07:04:14.372 |V| RiderDebuggerWorker           | Debugger worker MTA main thread:6 | Firing target exited to frontend
```

Debugger disconnect - this is probably normal behaviour given that the debugger didn't actually crash:

```
05:46:51.427 |V| Client                        | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10-Receiver:72 | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10 Connection was gracefully shutdown
05:46:51.427 |V| Client                        | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10-Receiver:72 | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10: Total traffic: sent 690, received 4436
05:46:51.427 |V| ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10-Sender| ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10-Receiver:72 | PAUSE ('Disconnected') :: state=AsyncProcessing
05:46:51.427 |V| Client                        | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10-Receiver:72 | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10: connecting to 127.0.0.1:51839.
05:46:51.427 |V| Client                        | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10-Receiver:72 | ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10: connection error for endpoint "127.0.0.1:51839". Connection refused 127.0.0.1:51839

--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [ExtendedSocketException]
Message = “Connection refused”
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException
HResult = E_FAIL=EFail=80004005
Source = System.Net.Sockets
NativeErrorCode = 61
StackTraceString = “
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) in DoConnect.il:line IL_007C mvid A973
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP) in Connect.il:line IL_00E6 mvid A973
     at JetBrains.Rd.Impl.SocketWire.Client.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<.ctor>b__0() in Client.il:line IL_0069 mvid E45C
”

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/2 [LoggerException]
Message = “ClientSocket-DebuggerWorkerHost::10: connection error for endpoint "127.0.0.1:51839". Connection refused 127.0.0.1:51839”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
InnerException = “Exception #1 at Root.InnerException”
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  at JetBrains.Util.LoggerBase.Log(LoggingLevel level, String message, Exception ex) in Log.il:line IL_0024 mvid A7F4
     at JetBrains.Diagnostics.LogEx.Verbose(ILog this, Exception ex, String message) in Verbose.il:line IL_0000 mvid 89A1 or Verbose.il:line IL_0008 mvid 89A1
     at JetBrains.Diagnostics.LogEx.Verbose(ILog logger, Exception ex, JetLogVerboseInterpolatedStringHandler& messageHandler) in Verbose.il:line IL_0000 mvid 89A1 or Verbose.il:line IL_0008 mvid 89A1
     at JetBrains.Rd.Impl.SocketWire.Client.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<.ctor>b__0() in Client.il:line IL_0069 mvid E45C
     at System.Threading.Thread.StartHelper.Callback(Object state) in Callback.il:line IL_0000 mvid 5DC4
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in RunInternal.il:line IL_0040 mvid 5DC4
”
```

Comment: I found a crash report on my system - stepping into the async method is causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. I've passed this on to Jetbrains, and I'll answer my own question with the solution once we eventually get to it.

Answer (score 2):

Using keywords from the system crash log I was finally able to find a network of relevant issues.

The two main ones are:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-69625
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68018

Looks like this is a dotnet issue on ARM Macs.

For now, there are two workarounds.

---

### Workaround #1

Enable the "Just My Code" feature of the dotnet debugger.

In Jetbrains Rider, this is done by *disabling* `Enable external source debug` under `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger`:
[image]

---

### Workaround #2

Add `DOTNET_ReadyToRun=0` as an environment variable when debugging your program.

Note that apparently this [does not work in every scenario](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68018#issuecomment-1366805140), so sometimes you may have to use workaround #1.

[image]